# How do I simplify this fraction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if i have ${X^{5/2}}$ all over $\dfrac{5}{2}$, how do I simplify? I have tried a couple of different ways but for the life of me I cannot get past this one. I would really appreciate any help given, sorry for the poor format of the question.

Comment: What does "all over" exactly? I don't know.

Comment: Alan, is the edit correct? If so, I will post an answer.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{\frac{a}b}{\frac{c}d}=\frac{ad}{bc}$$

Comment: I mean x^5/2 OVER 5/2. Again, apologies for poor wording/format.

Comment: I have edited for what you meant. Take a look when the edit is approved so that you can see how to do it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $a\div b=a\cdot \frac{1}{b}$ so that you have:

$$\frac{x^{2.5}}{5/2}=x^{2.5}\div\frac{5}{2}={x^{5/2}}\cdot\frac{2}{5},$$

leaving $\dfrac{2x^{5/2}}{5}$. Is this clear?

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you. Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: @AlanPiggott You're very welcome. Please accept so that it does not add to the unanswered queue.